# Browse and cleanup Gitlab pages files

Tags: gitlab

How can I browse and cleanup Gitlab pages files?

NB: I intend to build Gitlab pages for every branch (to host some CI reports). So I would like to trigger a cleanup stage when a branch is merged or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Although you properly sorted out your issues, I would just put an answer here as google search bring me here.

All old pages will always be deleted whenever you publishing new pages.

For detail, please refer to the thread from gitlab's forum. `dnsmichi`
from GitLab Team states this behaviour.

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/does-publishing-on-gitlab-pages-remove-old-files/39790